# Save m4a file after using authorization header to download

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, m4a

I am trying to download the m4a file of a recorded Zoom meeting from Zoom cloud. [Here](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/webhook-reference/recording-events/recording-completed) is the Zoom documentation on completed recording webhooks I am referencing. Specifically, I am trying to implement the section where Zoom describes the `download_token` in its schema explanation.

This is what I have so far:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import sys
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/notification/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def notification():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.json
        # pp.pprint(content)
        if content['event'] == 'recording.completed':
            process_recording(content['download_token'], content['payload']['object']['recording_files'])
    return 'This should be where the webhook sends info to'

def process_recording(download_token, recordings_list):
    recording = next(
                (recording for recording in recordings_list if recording["recording_type"] == 'audio_only'),
                None)
    
    url = recording['download_url']
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + download_token + ' --header content-type:'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('An error has occurred.')
```

Am I converting the curl command correctly? The curl command should be in this format:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url (download_url) \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer (download_token) \
  --header 'content-type: application/json'
```

Furthermore, how do I save the m4a file? What exactly does my `response` variable store?

Comment: You always can use a debugger https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2020/07/07/python-101-debugging-your-code-with-pdb/ or just `print(response)` or `print(type(response))`

Comment: Response seems to hold the http response status code. As of right now, my response is "<Response [401]>" and as a result, my program prints "An error has occurred"

Comment: `401` means not authorized

Comment: Hmmm... i'm not sure why I would not be authorized. Can someone confirm if I have translated the curl request to python correctly? Perhaps the error is caused by a faulty python request?

Comment: I am authorized to download the audio file if I use Zoom's URL query parameter ({download_url}/?access_token={download_token}) URL. This means that my permissions/authorization must be set up correctly, right? This seems to indicate that it is my authorization header in my curl request that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header is wrong...

compare...

```
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + download_token + ' --header content-type:'
    }
```

with

```
  --header 'authorization: Bearer (download_token) \
  --header 'content-type: application/json'
```

The value for the `authorization` header should be

```
"Bearer (%s)" % download_token
```

or

```
f"Bearer ({download_token})"
```

if you use Python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: What does the `f `in front of `f"Bearer ({download_token})` do? Is it wrong to simply do `'Bearer ' + download_token`?

Comment: That is the new string formatting technique, introduced with Python 3.6 - see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: Yes, it replaces the variable inside the braces with the value of it. Please note, that the parenthesis still stay.